# Toggle Multiple Hotkeys with Loop

Tags: toggle, autohotkey, hotkeys

I'm somewhat new to AutoHotKey. I made a toggleable macro that maps the WASD keys to the arrow keys.

The original code works but I'm trying to enable the hotkeys with a loop which is currently giving me a Nonexistent Hotkey error. How can I fix this loop, so that it works like the hard-coded nightmare below it?

```
for i in macros {
    Hotkey, % keys[i], % macros[i], % state ; <<< This line is causing the error
}
```

```
arrowsActive := 0
; CTRL + WASD --> arrow keys
Enter::
    arrowsActive := not arrowsActive
    macros := [arrowUp1, arrowLeft1, arrowDown1, arrowRight1, arrowUp2, arrowLeft2, arrowDown2, arrowRight2]
    keys := [W, A, S, D, W, A, S, D]
    state = Off
    if arrowsActive {
        state = On
    } 
    for i in macros {
        Hotkey, % keys[i], % macros[i], % state
    }
    ;Hotkey, W, arrowUp1, state       
    ;Hotkey, A, arrowLeft1, state     
    ;Hotkey, S, arrowDown1, state     
    ;Hotkey, D, arrowRight1, state    
    ;Hotkey, W Up, arrowUp2, state
    ;Hotkey, A Up, arrowLeft2, state
    ;Hotkey, S Up, arrowDown2, state
    ;Hotkey, D Up, arrowRight2, state
Return
arrowUp1: 
    send, {Up Down}
Return
arrowUp2: 
    send, {Up Up}
Return
arrowLeft1:
    send, {Left Down}
Return
arrowLeft2: 
    send, {Left Up}
Return
arrowDown1: 
    send, {Down Down}
Return
arrowDown2: 
    send, {Down Up}
Return
arrowRight1: 
    send, {Right Down}
Return
arrowRight2: 
    send, {Right Up}
Return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of your problems seem to be with understanding the [legacy vs expression syntax](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Language.htm#expressions-vs-legacy-syntax) in AHK v1. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61999880/3813732) is also a previous answer of mine about legacy syntax and expression syntax. You might find some help from it.

But now to the actual problems:

```
macros := [arrowUp1, arrowLeft1, arrowDown1, arrowRight1, arrowUp2, arrowLeft2, arrowDown2, arrowRight2]
keys := [W, A, S, D, W, A, S, D]
```

You're in an expression here, so what you're trying to do is create an array that includes values from the variables `arrowUp1`, `arrowLeft1`, ..., `W`, `A`,... But those variables don't exist, so you end up creating two arrays that are full of absolutely nothing. Just empty elements.
What you were trying to do is

```
macros := ["arrowUp1", "arrowLeft1", ...
keys := ["W", "A", ...
```

Also in your `keys` array, you didn't specify `w up`, `a up`,... for the second half of the keys.

Other than that, it would work. But of course, the implementation could be a lot better.
Let's make it better:

```
remaps := { w: "Up"
          , a: "Left"
          , s: "Down"
          , d: "Right" }

Enter::
    ;store this variable's value in the global scope, so it can be referred to
    ;on the following runs of this hotkey subroutine
    global arrowsActive := !arrowsActive

    for key, arrowKey in remaps
    {
        loop, 2
        {
            ;first loop for hotkeys when pressing down
            ;second loop for hotkeys when releasing keys

            keyFunction := Func("SendKey").bind(arrowKey, (A_Index - 1) ? true : false)
            Hotkey, % key ((A_Index - 1) ? " Up" : ""), % keyFunction, % arrowsActive ? "On" : "Off"
        }
    }
return

SendKey(key, release := false)
{
    SendInput, % "{" key (release ? " Up" : "") "}"
}
```

Useful documentation links to understand the code:

- [KeyValue pair object](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Objects.htm#Usage_Associative_Arrays)
- [Global variables](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Functions.htm#Global)
- [Bound function object](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/misc/Functor.htm#BoundFunc)
- [A_Index](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Variables.htm#Index)
- [Ternary operator ?:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator)

The answer also utilizes the fact that you shouldn't need to specify a `Down` hotkey. If you have e.g. hotkeys `a` and `a up`, the hotkey `a` gets called everything Windows' repeat key functionality triggers and repeats a key while you hold it down. And then `a up` gets called when a is released.

If something else is unclear about the answer, feel free to ask.